# jQuery UI autocomplete - use my custom ID instead of the default one

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using jQuery UI autocomplete on different inputs, and I get the source data from a DB.
In my `DB` I have an ID, and I'd like to use my `ID` (from my DB) instead of the default `ui-id-xxx`, is it possible?

I need this, as i'm writing some e2e tests and it is a pain at the moment, cause jQuery autocomplete ids are incrementing everytime I open the dropdown list.

here's some code (coffeescript):

```
@$el.find('.checker').autocomplete
      source: @query
      select: @updateModelInput
      change: @updateModelInput


query: (req, resp) ->
    queryData = {
      search: req.term
    }
    $.ajax
      type: "POST"
      url: cfg.baseDir + '/query.php'
      data: queryData
      cache: false
      success: (data) ->
        formatted = []
        l = JSON.parse(data)
        _.each l, (row) ->
          if row.brand != null
             txt = row.manufacturer + " | " + row.id
          else
             txt = row.manufacturer + " | " + row.id
          obj =
             label: txt
             value: txt
             id: row.id
          formatted.push obj
          return
        resp(formatted)
        console.log formatted
      return
 return
```

in the console, everything is returned properly, and on the jQuery UI list as well. The only part that is missing is my ID.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Still working on this? Take a look at the `_renderItem()` from the API: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem

Comment: Hi, no, at the end I decided to use this library here: https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/